# Can/should a player roll for failure on his own action?

Tags: cthulhu-dark

In [Cthulhu Dark](http://thievesoftime.bigcartel.com/cthulhu-dark) you only run the risk of botching an action completely "if someone thinks it would be more interesting if you failed" and rolls against you; otherwise your roll indicates the degree to which you succeed (on a scale of 'barely' to 'brilliantly').

**Should a player be permitted to call for the chance of failure on his own action?** I'm reasonably sure the rules don't anticipate it, so I'm not going to ask if it's intended to work that way: instead, I'm curious what--if any--repercussions there would be from introducing self-imposed chances of failure. Will the system or gameplay crumple up anywhere if I allow it?

In particular, I've noticed that Mythos storytelling/gameplay is usually more failure-focused than typical 'heroic' RPG gameplay. Cthulhu Dark seems unusual for a Lovecraftian system in that regard, and so I'm less comfortable with casually implementing edge cases of its failure mechanic.

Comment: Have you actually faced the situation, or are you simply moving on a theoretical area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a category answer, but interpretations on the text. Here are mine:

## RAW

> If someone thinks it would more interesting if you failed, they describe how you might fail and roll a die.

I think it's the pronoun "they" is open to interpretation, but it says when someone think. Are you someone? Yes you are, so I don't see any reason you can't call a failure roll.

## RAI

What did the author intend when he wrote that rule? I think that failure could only happen when it's interesting. When it's interesting? When someone thinks it would be. As I don't think the game has a competitive spirit, again I see no reason why you couldn't think a failure could be interesting.

Note that a possibility here is, if you think the failure would be so interesting, why roll? You could instead declare that your character fails, without losing time in making a roll.

## What could possibly go wrong?

I have never played Cthulhu Dark, so I'm not talking by experience, just applying the logic, and my experience in other systems.

I see the impact of allowing a player challenge his own action as very small, tending to none. As your character don't get a benefit from such challenge, I don't think it can be used to abuse the game. Players would usually use it (if they would use it at all) just for dramatic effect, or to add some emotion, so improving the story (or at least trying).

The only way I can think of a player could possibly want to challenge his success would be for metagaming purposes. For instance, a character is trying to save another character, but the player want him to die instead. Or maybe the character is trying to open a door that the player know has a great danger behind. Or the player want his character to arrive later at a scene to avoid its dangers. Those situations are quite exceptionally, anyway, and probably so uncommon we can still say allowing that type of challenges would have very little impact.

Summing it up, I think that a player rolling for his own failure has little effect, mostly dramatic, and low impact on the course on the game. Also, I think players would typically use this possibility very rarely, perhaps once in a session, if they would use it at all.

## Then, would I allow a player rolling for his own failure?

I would, as I think it can be justified by RAW and RAI. Anyway, I would discourage it. The text says *"If someone thinks it would more interesting if you failed"*, so I would tell the player if you think it would be more interesting that your character fail, then make it fail. Making several rolls (the regular one, the challenge rol, and the rerolls) for one action that is more interesting to fail seems only to slow the game.

## So, you don't think the game's Cthulhu Mythos context with that genre's traditional focus on failure and uncertainty factors in to this at all?

I'm keeping in mind this system is designed for a Cthulhu Mythos setting when interpreting which is its spirit. Apart from that, considerating the focus you said, I don't think I can add something that could improve my answer. Anyway, I don't think you should always assume a traditional take on a subject on a new system that approaches that subject, meaning previous Cthulhu games focus on failures don't mean new Cthulhu games should use the same focus.

Comment: @BESW I have no experience with the game. My answer is based exclusively on reading the manual of the link you provided, so I don't fully know the real impact of allowing one to test his own failure (my guess is close to none). About the manual including referring to "both" player I would say that it's expressed that way because the normal case is that there are two players implied (although according to manual there could be more and won't be "both"). I think that in the special case you are asking for the player doing the action and the player challenging it are both the same.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear: I don't think the game expected this interpretation so I don't see any point in delving into intent; instead I'm asking about the consequences of the interpretation on the system and gameplay. I'm not sure how your answer is addressing the implications of rolling for one's own failure.

Comment: So, you don't think the game's Cthulhu Mythos context with that genre's traditional focus on failure and uncertainty factors in to this at all?

Comment: @BESW I'm keeping in mind this system is designed for a Cthulhu Mythos setting when interpreting which is its spirit. Apart from that, considerating the focus you said, I don't think I can add something that could improve my answer. Anyway, I don't think you should always assume a traditional take on a subject on a new system that approaches that subject, meaning previous Cthulhu games focus on failures don't mean new Cthulhu games should use the same focus.

Comment: Hmm. Please edit that into your answer.

Comment: For what it's worth: no, I didn't intend that players could roll against themselves. Still, just because I didn't intend it doesn't mean it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Graham I was just going to suggest BESW to contact you about his concerns.

Answer (score 1):

A general way to check these things:

Look at the various variables in a situation.
Map out, either mentally or on paper, the interactions between each one.
Does your change introduce a new dominant strategy, one that is always a good option?
Does your change cause a "short circuit" in the rules?
If not, you're probably good.

In this case I don't see the gameplay going to pot if the player can roll against themself.
What does a player gain by failing that offsets the chance of failure? (my answer: excitement) Does that unbalance the game? (my answer: No)

Comment: Good rule of thumb! However, I'm concerned that the Mythos context may change the expected gain/fail boundaries in ways unfamiliar to more typically 'heroic' RPG experiences. Got any notions about that?

Comment: Gain can be catagorised in a number of ways, but in this case I don't see it being a problem. If you were running, say, a *drama point* based system you may have an issue, but CD is pretty straight forward on this front. Give it a shot. If I'm wrong, let me know!